# C# Stack with deletable elements

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I need a stack structure that also allows the for the deleting of elements. I can't find anything like this in the .Net framework. Which structure provides the best basis for me to implement this?

Comment: I use both Java and C#/VB.Net at work, and the Java Stack collection *does* have a remove(Object) method (because the Collection interface does).  It's interesting that .NET's Stack doesn't.  Now that I know, it can't trip me up later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a LinkedList as it has methods for AddFirst (Push) and RemoveFirst (Pop). But then it also has a simple Remove method that can be used to remove in middle.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a `LinkedList<T>`? you'd have to wrap it yourself to treat it as a `Stack<T>`, though. Of course, you could just use `List<T>` - but you'd have to absorb the cost of deleting from the middle...

Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class MyStack<T> {
    private readonly LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
    public void Push(T value) {
        list.AddLast(value);
    }
    public int Count { get { return list.Count; } }
    public T Pop() {
        LinkedListNode<T> node = list.Last;
        if(node == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        list.RemoveLast();
        return node.Value;
    }
    public bool Remove(T item) {
        return list.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

with whatever other methods / synchronization / etc you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
```

or

```
System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>
```

depending on the circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any list-like structure can be used as a stack.  You just push and pop items off the end.

If you need to delete items in the middle of the stack, you can use the built-in generic List's RemoveAt().

Answer (score 0):

By deleting of elements do you mean removing items that are not at the top of the stack?

One way you could do it is use a List and then use extension methods to implement the stack like behavior (coded in notepad, apologies for any minor errors).  You can then also do special handling (maybe you want to return null or throw an exception if the list is empty, maybe you want to make sure that the item is not already in the list, etc.

```
public static void Push<T>(this IList<T> list, T item)
{
    list.InsertAt(0, item);
}

public static T Pop<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    if(list.Count > 0)
    {
        T value = list[0];
        list.RemoveAt(0);
        return value;
    }
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: it would be better to add-to/remove-from the *end* of the list - otherwise you need to do a lot of copying every time you do anything...

Comment: I would go with @Marc answer if you need more control over your list.  If you are just doing simple things and need a stack like functionality I would use mine.  Something to keep in mind is to implement IEnumerable if you want linq support over your list.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the approach - simply the orientation of the list... it is much more expensive to to all the work at the "0" end...